# WebSocket connection is taking long time and failed

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket, https, wss

I created a secure websocket using this,

```
const Socket = require("websocket").server
const https = require("tls")
const fs = require('fs');

//certificate information
const  certificate = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/home/WebRTC/ssl/webrtc.crt",'utf8'),
    key: fs.readFileSync("/home/WebRTC/ssl/webrtc.key",'utf8')
};

const server = https.createServer(certificate,(req, res) => {})


server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000...")
})

const webSocket = new Socket({ httpServer: server })
```

and created the web client using this,

```
const webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://ip:3000")

webSocket.onerror= (event) => {
    alert("Connection error occured");
    
}

webSocket.onopen = (event) =>{
    alert("Connection established");
}

webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
    alert("Message received");
}
```

1. Im using https. Created a self signed certificate
2. wss://ip:3000. here the IP is the certificate resolving IP. These files are hosted in a publicly accessible server

But when I put the request, it takes a lot of time and gives and error.

"WebSocket connection to 'wss://ip:3000/' failed: "

Please be kind enough to help

Comment: You have not created any websocket's at the server end, you will need to handle the upgrade for websocket if your doing all this manually.

Comment: Care to explain? I'm like really new to the concept.

Comment: Well doing a websocket server in pure node, there are a few things you need to do -> https://medium.com/hackernoon/implementing-a-websocket-server-with-node-js-d9b78ec5ffa8   But to save you all that hassle, I would use a well maintained package that handles all this for you -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws